# Rails Slick Carousel Dynamic Data Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, carousel

I'm using slick to create a carousel. To use this gem I need to set up my classes like, example A:

```
<div class="someclass">
  <div>some data</div>
  <div>some data</div>
  <div>some data</div>
  <div>some data</div>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to do this with data from a database.
A shoe has many socks.

```
class ShoesController
  def show
    @shoe = Shoe.find(params[:id])
    @socks= @shoe.socks
  end
```

views/shoes/show.html.erb

```
<%= render @socks %>
```

views/socks/_sock.html.erb

```
<div class="someclass">
<div><%= sock.sock_name %></div>
</div>
```

My data should be coming out like

```
<div class="someclass">
  <div>sockname1</div>
  <div>sockname2</div>
  <div>sockname3</div>
</div>
```

But I'm not getting a carousel.

In my assets/javascript folder I have initialize.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.someclass').slick([
      dots: true
  })
```

In assets/javascripts/applicaiton.js

```
//= require jquery.slick
//= require initialize
```

My data arranges appropriately outside of the slick class "someclass". If I manually put in dummy data like example A directly into shoes/show.html.erb it arranges into a carousel. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your views/socks/_sock.html.erb, your template should render that:

```
<div class="someclass">
  <div>sockname1</div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
  <div>sockname2</div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
  <div>sockname3</div>
</div>
```

And that is not what you want. Your `<div class='someclass'></div>` node should be outside the socks loop.

Try something like that :

views/shoes/show.html.erb

```
<div class="someclass">
   <%= render @socks %>
</div>
```

views/socks/_sock.html.erb

```
<div><%= sock.sock_name %></div>
```